# How to format DTSTART and DTEND in ical.js for all day events?

Tags: icalendar

I'm newly using the ical.js library to parse and aggregate multiple ical sources.
https://github.com/kewisch/ical.js

This works fine in most cases, but in the case of all day events, the resulting ical file has wrong data in the DTSTART and DTEND fields.

All day events should have values with only the date in it
DTSTART:20231008
DTEND:20231013

But ical.js does generate this:
DTSTART:2023-10-08T::
DTEND:2023-10-13T::

Has anyone an idea on how to format them correctly, so they are ical standard compliant?
The ical.js has some "designer" which might help in these cases, but so far I'm missing on how to apply them on the toString() call which generates the ical file

https://github.com/kewisch/ical.js/issues/620